# Mobile device DOM block

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, dom-events

I have created simple header bars. Each of them will send a request when clicked, but on the mobile device (doesn't matter which one but even desktop Google Chrome mobile mod on the console) DOM begin to get blocked and stops working at all.
I suspect that:

1. when user clicked button I send very long get request
2. I bind new listeners (again and again) but not this header bar

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the issue. Do your best to create http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

How did you attach your click events ? It should not be complicated.

Here is a simple code sample that should work (also on mobile browsers):

**HTML snippet:**

```
<button id="myBtn">Click here to load content</button>
<div id="contentContainer"></div>
```

**Javascript (using jQuery) snippet:**

```
$('#myBtn').on('click',function(){

    // show some indication to the user that you are loading something
    $('#contentContainer').html('<strong>Loading content, please wait..</strong>');

    // do your ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.myapp.com/get/user-info',
    }).done(
    function(data){
        // all done - display the loaded content 
        $('#contentContainer').html(data);
    });
});
```

Use this as a use-case, if you are still getting "blocked" after executing javascript on a mobile device (clicking an element that is attached to a click handler is also executing js), it usually means that you have a javascript error - which causes the mobile browser to stop from running any more javascript until you fix the problem and reload the page.

Hope it helps a bit!

Comment: Thank you for help me I actually found problem,and it is 300ms delay on mobile,and I fixed with just css